# How to redirect tar unzipped files to a specific directory without creating a subfolder?

Tags: linux, tar

I'm using the following command to archive a folder:

```
tar zcf portal.tar.gz portal
```

then I'm untar'ing it using the following command:

```
tar xvzf portal.tar.gz -C /var/www/html/portal
```

But it seems like the "-C" switch creates another subfolder and then the path looks like so:

```
/var/www/html/portal/portal/files...
```

while I need it to be:

```
/var/www/html/portal/files...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that the following should work:

```
tar xvzf portal.tar.gz -C /var/www/html
```

by just simply going up one level in the directory structure.

Comment: The problem is that the filename of the portal directory is unknown as it's portal$GIT_TAG.tar.gz and since -C expects the destination folder to exist then I need to make sure it exists before unarchiving into there

Comment: yes, make sure '/var/www/html' exists before extracting. Or am I not understanding you correctly? Another way would probably be to omit the -C option and CD to there before extraction (as that's what the -C option does anyway), and cd makes sure the dir exists.

Comment: Yea that's what I did.. I changed it so I cd to the dir first and then extract.